Why does a div with display: block (default) not expand to vertically fit an image without overflow but changing it to display: inline-block does?
I have a div with a background color via background-image:linear-gradient, and with the div's default display as block it doesn't expand vertically to fit the image, the image overflows over the bottom border of the div. When I change the display of the div to inline-block it expands vertically to fit the entire image. The image has float:left and a header and description is to the right of it within the div. I understand the basic difference between block, inline, and inline-block but based on their properties I can't work out in my head why changing the display of the div to inline-block allows it to expand to fit the image. The div has height and width set to auto and the image has a fixed height and width. It's a simple question I guess and I have it working the way I want it to. I'm just trying to understand why it works the way it does. Sorry if this is a noob question. Thanks!
It is working as I want it to, just trying to understand why its working the way it is, thanks!
Within html doc:
<div class="header2">
    <img class="logo2" src="Images/jailhousejournals4.PNG" alt="Journal and Coffee in 
    jail cell"> 
    <h2 style="vertical-align:top;">Correctional Compositions</h2>
    <p>The following entries were composed within Fayette County Detention Center, while 
    serving a three-month sentence. During that time I began to formulate my literary 
    voice, through reflection and contemplation of my life and the world I inhabit. </p>
  </div>

Within stylesheet:
.header2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 82%, blue);
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Seymour One", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 100, 230);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 grey, 2px 2px 6px black;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 4px rgb(100, 50, 150);
}
.logo2 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 10px;
}


somewhere in the duplicate:  There are several ways to establish a block formatting context, but the solution I recommend is display: inline-block with width: 100%.

It works because inline-block combines characteristics of both inline and block elements.
Block elements: These elements ignore floated elements because floats are removed from the normal document flow, which means the block element does not expand to include the floated elements' height.
Inline elements: These elements include floated elements within their bounding box, which means they account for the height of the floated elements.
Therefore, when you use inline-block, it behaves like a block element in terms of layout but also includes floated elements within its bounding box, allowing it to expand vertically to fit the content.

Oh ok that makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to answer my noob question!
